# Generics and Class Inheritance confusion

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, covariance

I have the following block of code as a simplified example of a problem I'm having. but I get an error claiming that I cannot convert one type to another. I used LINQPad to test it.

```
void Main()
{
    LivingThing<Appendage> mysteryAnimal = new Cat();
}

public class Appendage { }
public class Paw : Appendage { }

public class LivingThing<TExtremity> where TExtremity : Appendage { }
public class Animal<TExtremity> : LivingThing<TExtremity> where TExtremity : Appendage { }
public class Cat : Animal<Paw> { }
```

Why can't I cast `Cat` to a `LivingThing<Appendage>` when I know that Cat's definition is using sub classes of `LivingThing` and `Appendage`?

Comment: Because `LivingThing<Paw>` is not `LivingThing<Appendage>` - read on covariance...

Comment: Classes are invariant - you could create an `ILivingThing<out TExtremity>` interface and then you could do `ILivingThing<Appendage> mysteryAnimal = new Cat();`.

Comment: Oh, so classes are covariant, but not generics?
`LivingThing<Appendage> mysteryAnimal = new Animal<Appendage>(); //works`
`LivingThing<Appendage> mysteryAnimal = new LivingThing<Paw>(); //does not`

Comment: The alleged duplicate is clearly related, but it does not answer OP's question on why it is impossible to do what he wants without changing things around. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to see why what you are trying to do cannot work without some modifications by adding a method to one of your classes:

```
public class LivingThing<TExtremity> where TExtremity : Appendage {
    private TExtremity extremity;
    public void SetExtremity(TExtremity e) {
        extremity = e;
    }
}
```

Now let's imagine that C# lets you do your assignment. Then it should let you do this:

```
public class Hand : Appendage { }
...
// Let's pretend this works
LivingThing<Appendage> cat = new Cat();
// Now that C# let us do the assignment above, it must allow this too,
// because Cat is a LivingThing and Hand is an Appendage:
cat.SetExtremity(new Hand());
```

Oops, we've got a Cat with a Hand! C# should not let us do this.

Doing what you wish to do may be possible if `LivingThing` had methods that *return* `TExtremity`, though. C# provides means for defining inheritance hierarchies that give you flexibility of assignments along the lines of what you tried. Here is your modified code that works:

```
void Main()
{
    ILivingThing<Appendage> mysteryAnimal = new Cat();
}

public class Appendage { }
public class Paw : Appendage { }

public interface ILivingThing<out TExtremity> where TExtremity : Appendage { }
// You have a choice of keeping Animal a class. If you do, the assignment
// Animal<Appendage> mysteryAnimal = new Cat()
// would be prohibited.
public interface IAnimal<TExtremity> : ILivingThing<out TExtremity> where TExtremity : Appendage { }
public class Cat : Animal<Paw> { }
```

There is a catch: neither `ILivingThing<TExtremity>` nor `IAnimal<TExtremity>` is allowed to have settable properties of type `TExtremity` or methods that take `TExtremity` as an argument.

Comment: Very interesting... I popped your example into LINQPad to try it out and it hiccuped on a few issues. The `ILivingThing<out TExtremity>` on the IAnimal interface apparently needs to not be `out`? And `Cat` needs to inherit from the interface (not the class I had before).

Comment: I'm familiar with `out` on parameters of methods, but not using it with generics. Is there a good question SO or an article that covers them?

Comment: @NickAlbrecht [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), one of the designers of C# compiler, has a very nice series of posts about covariance. In [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/31/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-eight-syntax-options.aspx) he discusses syntax options for using `in` and `out` in template arguments before it got added to the language (see option #5).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot for the point in the right direction. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called "covariance"; assigning an instance of a generic class with a more derived generic parameter to a variable of a class with a less derived one.

In C#, this is not supported for classes. For interfaces, it must be explicitly specified. The following would compile:

```
void Main()
    {
        ILivingThing<Appendage> mysteryAnimal = new Cat();
    }

    public class Appendage { }
    public class Paw : Appendage { }

    public interface ILivingThing<out TExtremity> where TExtremity : Appendage { }
    public class Animal<TExtremity> : ILivingThing<TExtremity> where TExtremity : Appendage { }
    public class Cat : Animal<Paw> { }
```

Whether this will be acceptable for your actual code depends on how LivingThing is defined; if it is a "marker class" (no members; existing solely to be a point of derivation identifying its children as LivingThings), or an abstract class with no non-abstract members, it should work like a charm. If you have member code in this class, you'll need to extract a covariant interface from the class.

Comment: What if I did both, have member code in the base class (non abstract) but use an interface for using as the restriction on my generic where constraints?

Comment: Ok. Awesome I'll have to look into how I'm passing these instances around and determine when I actually need a strongly typed class or just an interface, and see if I can get it all sorted out. Thanks so much :-)